# Ruby on Rails SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am developing a simple app where a user can add a subject to a cart. Before I add the authentication I was able to add a subject to the cart but as I want a user to be able to has access to just his/her cart I used Devise to create User with authentication. Now, when I click on the button to add a subject to the cart I have the following error:

This is a snapshot of the error I get: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71IIy.png)

> SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: carts.user_id: INSERT INTO "carts" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  private

    def current_cart
      Cart.find(params[:user_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      cart = Cart.create
      params[:user_id] = cart.id
      cart
    end
end


    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :cart
end

class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

  scope :user_carts, ->(user) { where(['user_id= ?', user.id]) }

end

class AddUsersToCarts < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def up
    add_reference :carts, :user, index: true
    Cart.reset_column_information
    user = User.first

    Cart.all.each do |cart|
      cart.user_id = user.id
      cart.save!
    end

    change_column_null :carts, :user_id, false
    add_foreign_key :carts, :users
  end

  def down
    remove_foreign_key :carts, :users
    remove_reference :carts, :user, index: true
  end

end
```

Edit: I added the schema.rb below:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151210213408) do

  create_table "carts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id",    null: false
  end

  add_index "carts", ["user_id"], name: "index_carts_on_user_id"

  create_table "line_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "subject_id"
    t.integer  "cart_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "subjects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title",       null: false
    t.string   "code",        null: false
    t.text     "description", null: false
    t.integer  "credits",     null: false
    t.string   "lecturer",    null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  add_index "subjects", ["title"], name: "index_subjects_on_title", unique: true

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Comment: Please post your `schema` your data table has some field which should not be `null` as `null: false` but in `insert` you make it `null` and got that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `current_cart` method does not make much sense.

1. You cannot find the user's cart by calling `Cart.find(params[:user_id])`, because that looks for a cart by an `id` (not by an `user_id`).
2. `Cart.create` fails, because you do not provide an `user_id` that is required (your database migrations says that the filed cannot be null).
3. Furthermore, `params[:user_id] = cart.id` changes the `params` hash, but not the new cart.

Change that method to something like this (using [`find_or_create_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by)) and use the `current_user.id` instead of `params[:user_id]`:

```
def current_cart
  Cart.find_or_create_by(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

Comment: I also think that this method is not working so I played with it a bit but with no result, I tried your proposal but still I get the same error. Is it possible for some reason it doesn't recognize the field  "t.integer  "user_id",    null: false"?

Comment: Do you provide a `user_id` in the URL of your page? If not then `params[:id]` will be empty. Or you you have a `current_user` method in your app?

Comment: I don't have user_id in the URL, when I click the button to add a subject to the cart, I add it using a line_item with the subject's id. I do not have a current_user method though, any suggestions?

Comment: As I mentioned I used Devise to create User and yes only a logged user can see his cart which I have already achieved. The problem arises when I try to add an item to the cart, I think it can't identify the cart to which it is supposed to add this item.

Comment: I want to store the cart for a given user so that whenever he logs back he can access his cart with the same items in it instead of using just the current session. And I have done this but whenever I try to add something to the cart it seems it can't find the cart.

Comment: Yes, now I managed to fix it. Understood where my mistake is. Thank you very much!